# Python open file in write mode IOError

Tags: python

I'm receiving an IOError when trying to create a file using open() in python, which only seems to occur for a single filename. The directories definitely exist and permissions are granted, the loop created around 1000 files successfully. When `epic = "CON"` in the code below I receive the "No such file or directory" error, but it works fine for other values.

```
f = open('data\\LSE\\%s.csv' % epic.strip(),'w')
f.write(u.read())
f.close()
```

Could this be a race issue? The files are created quite quickly.

I'm new to python so if there's something obvious I missed, apologies!

Comment: What does `print repr(epic)` print?

Comment: 'COD'. There's more weirdness, using the console, open('data\\LSE\\COD',w) gives "Bad File Descriptor" but CAD, CO, CODD all work fine. I also tried testing this in other directories and encounter the same behaviour

Comment: open('data\\LSE\\COD.csv',w) or open('data\\LSE\\COD',w)?

Comment: Ah, sorry, COD should be CON, that was the string that I was having issues with

Comment: Michael, I tried both (see my correction, it was actually CON sorry), without a file extension it gives "Bad File Descriptor" and with it gives "No such file or directory"

Comment: Can you try putting the absolute path, I am wondering if it just can't find the file by the relative path.

Comment: I've figured out what the issue is, it's a reserved name in Windows, did not know that! Issue resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are running this code on Windows, which still contains some legacies from MS-DOS 1.0.  `CON` is a special name for the console device.  You can't use it as a file name.  The earliest versions of MS-DOS did not support directories, nor did they support the so-called "extension" of the 8.3 file naming pattern.  As a result, the name is special regardless of the directory and regardless of extension.

Some references:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/22/55388.aspx
- https://superuser.com/questions/86999/unable-to-rename-a-folder-or-a-file-as-con

---

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:
>
> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks dsh, I suppose I'll have to change my stock ticker file naming convention!